# How to create live template like `condition.if` that natively supported by JetBrains IDE?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, live-templates

In JetBrains IDE including PHPStorm, PyCharm, IntelliJ Idea, I can type this

```
age > 0.if
```

Then press tab and I will get

```
if (age > 0) {
}
```

In my application I need to type a lot of these:

```
    const resPartnerFactory = new BaseModelFactory(ResPartner);
    const accountChartTemplateFactory = new BaseModelFactory(AccountChartTemplate);
    const resCompanyFactory = new BaseModelFactory(ResCompany);
```

And want to create a live template like

```
    ResPartner.bmf
```

I have created these

[image]
[image]

How to finishe the `.bmf` part?

Comment: Those are different things: the `.if` is a [Postfix completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion) (that can transform the context a bit) while on screenshots you are trying to use [ordinary Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) that will replace entered abbreviation with the predefined template.

Comment: The help page for Postfix completion shows how it can be done. As I understand it will be something like `const $EXPR$Factory = new BaseModelFactory($EXPR$);` You can also look at the [Custom Postfix Templates plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates) -- it offers more of them + the ability to edit or create new ones (which was limited/not much possible until now, at very least in PhpStorm)